# Ranking lines of a file according to number of occurrences

Tags: ruby, sorting, io

I recently dived into Ruby, so I want to improve this code. Is this good enough?

```
def ranksystem
    logfile = IO.readlines("some_logfile.log")
    logfile.each do |value|
      value.gsub!(/[\n]+/, "")
    end
    logfile.delete("")

    logcount = Hash.new(0)

    logfile.each do |v|
      logcount[v] += 1
    end

    logarray = logcount.sort_by {|k,v| v}.reverse

    finalreturn = ""

    logarray.each_with_index do |value, index|
      finalreturn = finalreturn + "Rank #{index+1} : #{value[1]} (#{value[0]})\n"
    end

    finalreturn

end
```

This code reads each line in log file like this:

> ```
> apple
> orange
> apple
> apple
> apple
> apple
> orange
> orange
> banana
> banana
> ```

and converts like this:

> ```
> Rank 1 : 4 (apple)
> Rank 2 : 3 (orange)
> Rank 3 : 2 (banana)
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Cool" enough? It seems fine, if procedural. Depends what you mean by cool.

I might combine a few steps. I'd also refactor and not put everything into one method, since each separate "chunk" does very distinct, and different, things. Separation makes testing easier.

The below isn't necessarily any better (and the chunk that creates the report may actually be worse--I'm not sure; it'd be less efficient), but it provides some alternate avenues to explore further.

```
def get_log_lines name
  logfile = IO.readlines(name)
  logfile.collect { |l| l.gsub(/\n+/, "")}.reject { |l| l == "" }
end

def ranksystem
  loglines = get_log_lines "some_logfile.log"
  logcount = Hash[loglines.group_by {|l| l}.collect {|k, v| [v.size, k]}]
  i = 0
  logcount.keys.sort.reverse.collect { |n| i += 1; "Rank #{i}: #{n} (#{logcount[n]})" }.join("\n")
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function would be better if it accepted an argument for the filename.

I think that you are on the right track with `logcount = Hash.new(0)` and `logcount[v] += 1`.  However, you would be better off instantiating `logcount` *before* starting to process the file.  That way, `logcount` is your only data structure.  You don't have to construct an array using `IO#readlines`, and you can discard empty lines on the fly.

The block passed to `sort_by` could be smarter.  The parameters could be more meaningfully named.  Sort by `-count` instead of `count` to get the list in descending order without having to call `reverse`.

To build the result string, use `Array#join`.

```
def ranksystem(file)
  logcount = Hash.new(0)

  File.new(file).each_line do |line|
    line.chomp!
    logcount[line] += 1 unless line.empty?
  end

  # Note: .each_with_index.map requires Ruby >= 1.8.7
  # (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4697573)
  logcount.to_a
          .sort_by { |line, count| -count }
          .each_with_index
          .map { |value, index| "Rank #{index+1} : #{value[1]} (#{value[0]})" }
          .join("\n")
end
```